# How can I post following link that includes fragment with java method?

Tags: support, comments, markdown, formatting

I had a few posts recently when an answer required posting links with fragments, that include a method declaration with an argument list.

```
http://somesite.com/api/#myMethod(arg1, arg2)
```

That pattern is usually used for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) API documentation.

You can notice that it does not work properly on Stack Overflow when you try to include it as a regular link.

Shouldn't it be corrected or is there a workaround for those kind of links?

**Update**

As mentioned by [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson), the link format below works in post preview mode, but it does not work in posts and comments.

```
[some link](http://somesite.com/api/#myMethod(arg1, arg2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't. That's not a valid link as there is absolutely no link which can be considered valid with a space in the middle of it. If you want the last part of the link to be recognized, you need to encode the space, like so:

```
http://example.com/api/#myMethod(arg1,%20arg2)
```

Result: http://example.com/api/#myMethod(arg1,%20arg2)

Otherwise, it's a separate word that is not a part of the link.

Comment: @gevorg The comment Markdown doesn't work the same (it's a completely separate parser). It should work in a post, though.

Comment: Ahh..true, works for posts and does not for comments

Comment: Eh, interesting. Apparently it only works in preview.

Comment: I didn't dare to post here, but for some reason I was sure it is not working, because I tried all possible versions with markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... I can just use HTML `<a>` tag for that.

[sample link](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html#CSVReader(java.io.Reader,%20int,%20com.opencsv.CSVParser))