# Different markdown rendering in preview and or content

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

I have asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118219/what-is-the-use-of-calling-surfaceholder-setfixedsize) and it makes a reference to a [specific Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFixedSize(int, int)). When I'm in the editor the preview renders the link correctly, but when the post is displayed the link is broken.

Preview render:

[image]

Final render:

[image]

Comment: Did you check http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327188/972240 ?

Comment: You can use HTML `<a>` tag for that case or encode spaces with `%20`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the () in the URL is messing up the Markdown parsing. I edited the question to use the link formatting:

```
[to be set to the tiny size of 20x10 pixels][1]
...
  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFixedSize(int,%20int)
```

And the question now renders correctly.

EDIT

After further testing I cannot get the same thing to happen again unless there is a space in the URL instead of the %20. I am not sure exactly what happened since the revision does not show the %20 in the URL, but it was in there when I edited the question.

Comment: Actually the problem is in the space character used in url, in your sample you encoded it with `%20`.

Comment: @gevorg Is the %20 still considered a space?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be so.